# keyboard hides the layout components

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

How do I prevent the keyboard from hiding the layout when it pops up? I'm using this line of code to resize the layout when the keyboard open up.

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

The result is, while the screen resizes for some devices, it doesn't to the extent I want for other devices. For example here's what the layout looks on one device:

[image]

and here's how it looks on another device:

[image]

In the second image as you can see, the login button is half visible due to the keyboard overlapping it. Also the "Login" Text at the top is chopped off. How do I make it so the layout looks the same for all devices?

**Edit**

I also have this line in my Menifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".AccountActivity" android:label="yourtime" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"></activity>
```

here's the code for the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:weightSum="100"
android:id="@+id/signinwrapper"
android:background="#F73494">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:text="Your home of Entertainment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_weight="45">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:background="@drawable/editor"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:background="@drawable/editor"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ProgressBarStyle"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstyles"
        android:textColor="#F73494"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that in code.  Do it in the AndroidManifest xml file.  You'll get odd results doing it in code, especially if you have dialogs.

What doing that mode does is force your app to resize to go above your keyboard.  However-  some things just take space.  If your layout has sufficient whitespace to resize, it will.  If it doesn't, then the keyboard will still cover part of the app.  You didn't post your layout, so I can't give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have updated my original question. Please have a look.

Comment: I notice one thing-  your weightsum is set to 100, but the sum of all weights is actually 105.  Delete the weightsum on the top linear layout and see if it fixes things.  Note that you'll still have issues-  look how the bottom of the word "login" is cut off.  No way to fix that other than to just give it more space.  The only way I can see doing that is by making your image smaller or your text size smaller, there isn't a lot of vertical whitespace to kill.

Comment: Ohh I didn't realize that. I made the text and the image as small as I could but if I make them too small, they will look too tiny on devices with larger screen size. What's the best way to implement that layout with all those components without compromising anything. The Facebook app hides everything below the login button when the keyboard popsup but they can still manage everything inside a small screen. I don't have that device with layout issues so I'll have to test is later. Do we have any control over how much something resizes and what we want to display when the keyboard is open?

Comment: The biggest control you have would be to make the entire page less busy.  FB has very little content on their login page-  they have a lot of vertical whitespace, but very little content-  a logo two text boxes and a button IIRC.  Its laid out in such a way that when the keyboard comes up the whitespace is reduced and everything fits.